# Prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n =0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n) _{n\ge 1}$ be a sequence of real numbers so that $\lim_{n\to\infty} (a_n^2-a_{n-1}a_{n+1})=0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} (a_{n+1}+a_{n-1})=0$. Prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n =0$. 
I observed that $a_n$ must be bounded because otherwise the second relation doesn't hold, but I can't see how to continue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(a_{n+1} + a_{n-1}) \to 0$ implies
$$(a_{n+1} + a_{n-1})^2 = a_{n+1}^2 + 2 a_{n+1} a_{n-1} + a_{n-1}^2 \to 0.$$
Combining this with the other assumption shows that
$$a_{n+1}^2 + 2 a_n^2 + a_{n-1}^2 \to 0$$
from which you may conclude $a_n \to 0$.